# Node.js + Sending API Request to Third Party Service

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node console app. In my app, I am trying to send some data to a third-party web service. I can successfully add data via the third-party web service via POSTMAN. In my Postman, I have a request setup like this:

**Headers**

```
api-key
{my key}

Content-Type
application/json
```

**Body**

```
{
  "value": [
    { 
      "@operation": "send",
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Hello",
      "position": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [90.000000, 0.000000] },
      "tags":["january", "friends"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am now trying to replicate sending this data via Node. In an attempt to do this, I've written the following:

```
var ops = {
  host: 'example.com',
  path: '/api/upload?version=2',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'api-key':'[my key]',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

var r = https.request(ops, (res) => {
  res.on('data', (d) => { 
    console.log(res.statusCode); 
    console.log(res.statusMessage);
  });
});

var data = {
  "value": [
    req.body.record    // req is passed in via express 
  ]
};
console.log(data);

r.write(JSON.stringify(data));
r.end();
```

When the line `console.log(data);` is executed, I see the following in the console window:

```
{ value:
   [ { '@operation': 'send',
       id: '1',
       name: 'Hello',
       position: [Object],
       tags:[Object]
    } ] }
```

I'm not sure if this is a printing problem or an actual problem. Either way, my real issue is that when I send my request, I see the following also printed in the console window:

```
400
Bad Request
```

That data looks correct. I don't understand why I'm getting a 400 when I try to send from Node. Yet, it works just fine from Postman. Does it have to do with the quotation marks? I thought JSON.stringify handled that.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, unless you have a really good reason not to, just use something like [request](https://github.com/request/request).  It's way easier/cleaner than trying to build it yourself.

I can't answer any more specifically without knowing what the API you're talking to is expecting.

Also, in your `res.on('data')`, just `console.log(req);` and see what else is hiding in there; it might help you solve this with your existing code.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, since it's a 400, doesn't that mean the error in on my side. The API is irrevlant in this case right? Or am I misunderstanding something about a 400.

Comment: Well, no, you're receiving a 400 from the API because the data you're posting is (probably) not what the API is expecting.  In the response (probably `response.body`) you'll find more details, so you should see what's there - it might help solve this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Instead of

```
console.log(data);
```

and then decide what is wrong. This will give me full data in way it is sent to server.

**Update:**
I have made quick experiment and received following output:

```
{"value":[{"@operation":"send","id":"1","name":"Hello","position":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[90,0]},"tags":["january","friends"]}]}
```

The difference with the original JSON is in way how the **coordinates** are sent to the web service (**as integers**), which can be your problem.

Comment: This wouldn't add any information to the investigation at all.

Comment: It will. console.log(data) dumps the object. so elements like position and tags are printed as "[Object]". You don't what you have in this object and how this object will be stringified. if console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) is used, in that case the real string which is posted to the service is logged. So it can be compared with the one which works in POSTMAN. Note that HTTP error 400 means "Bad request". In most cases the request data is not correct (malformed). It seems that the headers in both POSTMAN and node are the same, so the difference is somewhere in the body.